# Run function after t time

Tags: python

I got a problem is: have a variable total time is `t_total` after a time in `t_total` i want to run some function and the time continue count up or down to the end of `t_total`. It look like:
`---t1---t2--`
when time equal t1 run a function and in t2 run another function.
I tried to make a count function:

```
for t in range(t_total):
    t = t + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if t = t1:
        function1()
```

but if follow that function the count up will stop at time when run function1. So, have anyway to keep the count continue to run the function2?

Comment: you can't do two things at the same time - you need `threading` module to run `function1()` in second thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do using [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

```
import threading
for t in range(t_total):
    t = t + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if t = t1:
        threading.Thread(target=function1).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add into function 1 to start a new timer starting at time t. You can export the value of t, t1 and t2 into function 1 and continue a new timer.